# Distribution of the number of the correct answers

Tags: probability, proof-verification

There are $40$ questions in a test, $30$ questions are easy such that everyone can solve, $10$ questions are difficult such that no one can solve. $25$ students are going to do the test and each one of them choose randomly $5$ different questions such that different students are choosing the questions independently. To pass the exam the student must answer at least four questions.

> - **A.** Find the distribution of the number of the correct answers of one specific student

---

**My attempt:**

$\underline{P(X=1):}$

There are $40$ questions, so for one correct answer:

$\frac{30}{40}=3/4$ and also he should be wrong in his other four: $10/49\cap 9/38 \cap 8/37 \cap 7/36 $ , he can answer correctly in his first question OR in the second OR in the third OR in the fourth OR in the fifth, so I will multiply all by $\color{blue}5$

So the answer for $P(X=1)$ will be: $\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{10}{49}\cdot\frac{9}{38}\cdot\frac{8}{37}\cdot\frac{7}{36}\cdot \color{blue}5=\frac{75}{9842}$

$\underline{P(X=2):}$

The student should right in $2$ answers: $30/40\cap 29/39$ and he should be wrong in $3$ of his answers: $10/38\cap 9/37 \cap 8/36$

Now the two correct answers can be here:
$\underline{\text{v}}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{}$ or here 
$\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}$ or here: 
$\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}$ or here 
$\underline{}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{\text{v}}$
or here
$\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}$
or here
$\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}$
or here
$\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}$
or here
$\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}$
or here
$\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}$
or here
$\underline{}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}$
or here
$\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}$

so I will multiply the result by $\color{blue}{11}$

So the answer will be $P(X=2)=\frac{30}{40}\cdot\frac{29}{39}\cdot\frac{10}{38}\cdot\frac{9}{37}\cdot\frac{8}{36}\cdot\color{blue}{11}=\frac{1595}{18278}$

$\underline{P(X=3):}$

$\frac{30}{40}\cdot\frac{29}{39}\cdot\frac{28}{38}\cdot\frac{10}{37}\cdot\frac{9}{36}\cdot\color{blue}{11}\approx 0.30542$

$\underline{P(X=4):}$

$\frac{30}{40}\cdot\frac{29}{39}\cdot\frac{28}{38}\cdot\frac{27}{37}\frac{10}{36}\cdot\color{blue}{5}\approx 0.41648$

$\underline{P(X=5):}$

$\frac{30}{40}\cdot\frac{29}{39}\cdot\frac{28}{38}\cdot\frac{27}{37}\frac{26}{36}\cdot \color{blue}{1}=\frac{609}{2812}$

Is it correct?

Comment: don't forget  P(X=0)

Comment: You counted the case $\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{\text{v}}\underline{}\underline{}$ twice, which seems to be how you got $11$ cases for $X=2$ instead of $10$ cases. That is a pitfall of listing cases one by one instead of using a known formula to count them. But if you do list one at a time it helps to be more systematic about the listing, such as, list all the cases where the first question is correct, then all cases where the first is incorrect and the second is correct, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be much simpler, and avoid needless errors such as counting the multiplication factor for $P(X=2)$ and $P(X=3)$ as $11$ instead of $10$, if you use combinations instead, with a uniform formula,

$P(X) = \dfrac{\binom{30}{X}\binom{10}{5-X}}{\binom{40}{5}}$

e.g. $P(X=0)$ (which you forgot) $= \dfrac7{18278},\;\; P(X=1) = \dfrac{175}{18278}$

*Note*

Basically, there is nothing wrong with your approach. In general, my experience is that people **forget** the multiplication factor altogether, so unless some particular sequence has been specified, I prefer to use combinations rather than direct multiplication of probabilities.