# Distribution of the number of students that will fail in the exam

Tags: probability, proof-verification

There are $40$ questions in a test, $30$ questions are easy such that everyone can solve, $10$ questions are difficult such that no one can solve. $25$ students are going to do the test and each one of them choose randomly $5$ different questions such that different students are choosing the questions independently. To pass the exam the student must answer at least four questions.

> - $\color{gray}{\text{A. Find the distribution of the number of the correct answers of one specific student}}$
> - **B.** Find the distribution of the number of students (from the $25 $) that will fail in the exam

The answer for **A.** is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622261/distribution-of-the-number-of-the-correct-answers)

---

**My attempt for B:**

Because that the distribution of the number of the correct answers of one specific student is $P(X) = \dfrac{\binom{30}{X}\binom{10}{5-X}}{\binom{40}{5}}$

and there are $25$ students so omega will be all the students $|\Omega|=25$ so the answer for **B.** will be

### $P(Y)=\frac{1-P(Y) = \dfrac{\binom{30}{Y}\binom{10}{5-Y}}{\binom{40}{5}}}{25}$

$Y\in \{0,1,...,25\}$

> Is it correct?

Comment: Hint : The number of students failing in the exam is binomial distributed : $Y$~$B(25;p)$ , where $p$ denotes the probability that a specific student fails, which is $p=P(X\le 3)$, where $X$ is the number of questions the student can answer.

Comment: What does your last formula mean? It looks like you are dividing an entire equation by 25. I would expect something in which the variable is the number of students who fail, so if $Y$ is the number of failing students I can set $Y=6$ and plug that into the formula to find out how likely it is that $6$ students will fail.

Comment: @DavidK I etited

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by dividing an entire equation by 25. How can $P(Y)$ equal 1/25 of an equation? Also, what about the probability that $6$ students fail: then $Y=6$, and what is $\binom{10}{5-6}$? Do you get a value of $P(6)$ that seems reasonable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probability of picking $4$ or $5$ easy questions is
$$
p={\binom{10}{1}\binom{30}{4}\over\binom{40}{5}}+{\binom{30}{5}\over\binom{40}{5}}
$$
So propbability of failing the test is $f=1-p$. If $F$ is the number of students that fail the test,
$$
P(F=n)=\binom{25}{n}f^np^{25-n}
$$
which is a [Binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).